# How to install command line utility for use in puckel docker-airflow docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I am trying to install poppler-utils, within a puckel docker-airflow container, in-order that I can make a command-line call to pdftotext via an Airflow BashOperator. Details of how to setup and use pdftotext can be found [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/05/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-on-linux-gui.html), and I can confirm it works fine when installed directly on my Linux Mint (Ubuntu) O/S.

So, with my limited understanding of Docker / puckel docker-airflow, I headed to Dockerfile and amended it as follows (see bottom line):

```
RUN set -ex \
&& buildDeps=' \
    freetds-dev \
    libkrb5-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    git \
' \
&& apt-get update -yqq \
&& apt-get upgrade -yqq \
&& apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
    $buildDeps \
    freetds-bin \
    build-essential \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    apt-utils \
    curl \
    rsync \
    netcat \
    locales \
    poppler-utils \
    ...
```

However, when I spin up the container and try to run pdftotext (via the Airflow BashOperator or via the command line within a container execution), I get:

```
bash: pdftotext: command not found
```

Can someone please advise me on how to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: After you added `poppler-utils` to the Dockerfile, did you rebuild the Docker image `docker build .` or `docker-compose build`?

Comment: I have been running: docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml up -d as I believed that would be sufficient to install whatever was specified in Dockerfile at the point the container was created (it worked for a pip install that I added to the same section.) I have just tried docker build . but the situation is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Quick solution is:

Access the container id of airflow worker as root user

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                                        NAMES
c73425b30981        puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9   "/entrypoint.sh work…"   7 hours ago         Up 7 hours             5555/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8793/tcp                 airflow_worker_1
```

`docker exec -it --user root c73 /bin/bash`

Run apt get update
`root@c73425b30981:/usr/local/airflow# apt-get update`

Then install pdftext tool for Debian
`root@c73425b30981:/usr/local/airflow# apt-get install poppler-utils`

Then you will be able to use pdftotext command

`pdftotext {PDF-file} {text-file}`